# Cannot assign a value of type 'DateComponents' to a value of type 'String?'

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter, nscalendar

The following code doesn't compile and I'm not sure where to find the answers within Apple's documentation:

```
let birthdate = try currentHealthStore.dateOfBirthComponents()
        var formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM"
        var formattedDate = formatter.string(for: birthdate)
        self.ageValueLabel.text = birthdate
```

The error stems from the final line where it can't be converted to a string.

Comment: what is the value in `birthdate` and also tell the type

Comment: It is supposed to be the birthdate component from the HKHealthStore framework.  currentHealthStore is simply an object derived from the HKHealthStore class. @RajanMaheshwari

Comment: You need to write this 

self.ageValueLabel.text = formatter.stringFromDate(date)

Comment: just print the `birthday` components. There might be a problem with dateFormat

Comment: Most likely you mean `self.ageValueLabel.text = formattedDate`

Comment: I'm sorry and don't know how I missed that error...I was asking for the incorrect value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to assign a dateComponent value to label. But a label expects a String value. So yo just havr to do this.

```
self.ageValueLabel.text = formattedDate
```

Comment: `birthdate` is of type `DateComponents`. The code `String(birthdate)` won't even compile. Why was this answer up voted and accepted?